# Creating wrapper component

Tags: react-native, redux

I want to create a wrapper component like this:

Wrapper Component:

```
class WrapperComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Image source={someImage}>
          <App />
      </Image>);
  }
}
```

App:

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <WrapperComponent>
        <Text>Some text</Text>
      </WrapperComponent>
  }
}
```

I want to use this for the default things like a background image. Is there a way to do this? Sorry I am new in this language.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.2eei2qibi) link

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can create the wrapper using `props.children`

### Functional component

```
const WrapperComponent = ({ children }) => (
  <Image source={someImage}>
    {children}
  </Image>
);
```

### Class component

```
class WrapperComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Image source={someImage}>
          {this.props.children}
      </Image>);
  }
}
```

Whatever you'll put inside the `<WrapperComponent></WrapperComponent>` tags will be rendered.

Comment: Whenever I will push another screen it will be re-render and load again. I will fixed for all view. like iOS container view. it's possible in react native.

Comment: @KiritModi - can you explain more (or even open a new question)?

Comment: Yes, I want to fixed topview which is same all of view. So I create the Higher Order Component for TopView. but when it's re-render every time. I want to Fixed( not re- render)

Comment: You can use shouldComponentUpdate or React.memo. It's better if you open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

As per official docs 'Composition vs Inheritance' the Inheritance approach is not recommended. So, you can create `AwesomeWrapper.js` with the content:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native'; 

export const AwesomeWrapper = (props) => {
  return (
    <Image source={props.imageSource}>
      {props.children}
    </Image>
  );
}
```

and then use in your code like

```
    <AwesomeWrapper imageSource="...">
       ...
    </AwesomeWrapper>
```