# iOS Container Views in React Native

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, uicontainerview

In Xcode you can put two (or more) Container Views on one screen, and put two different View Controllers in them. This can help separate the code and avoid heavy View Controller code.

Is there a way this can be used in conjunction with React Native?

The use case is a screen with two containers. The top contains a UISearchBar - controlled with regular Swift code, and the bottom changes according the the users actions. One of those actions would show a React-driven View Controller, and other actions would use Swift View Controllers?

Is this kind of mixing possible?

Comment: I think this tutorial might be helpful to you: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

Comment: Did you see this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40111292/creating-wrapper-component