# Can I wrap a custom component around a regular component in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-component, react-functional-component

So I have a component that returns a button with some custom text and an icon. I'm pulling the icons from expo vector icons and so to use the icons I need to write something like:

```
<Icon_Name name"name"......>
```

I want to wrap my custom component around an icon or any other component, so then I can use various different icons within that component.

So I want my code to basically be:

```
<Custom_Component>
  <IconOrSomeOtherComponent />
</Custom_Component>
```

I want to somehow call that icon component within my custom component. Is this possible?

I know that I can pass in variables into a custom component like:

```
<Custom_Component someVariable="some variable" />
```

and then use "someVariable" within my the function of the component, but I was hoping to find a solution where I can just wrap a component and call the "wrapped" component inside the function of my "Custom_Component".

***I'm using functional components by the way, not class components.***

Comment: hi, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40111292/creating-wrapper-component

Comment: Yes you can. You can later use those nested component with `props.children` with `props` is the parameter you passed in functional component