# Passing in children to a HoC/Wrapper Component

Tags: react-native, parent-child

I'm trying to make a common component that would take in a child component as follows:

```
interface IComponentProps {
onPress: () => void;
};

type IHybridProps = IComponentProps & React.Component;

const ParentComponent: React.FC<IHybridProps> = (props:IHybridProps) => {
 const {onPress = () => void,} = props;
 return (
         <View>
            <Pressable onPress={() => onPress() }> {props.children} </Pressable>
        </View>);
};

const Screen: React.FC = (props) => {
return ( 
    <ParentComponent> 
         <Text>Test Component</Text>
    </ParentComponent>);
};
```

Attempting the code above, I would constantly receive a "text must be wrapped withing a  element" error. I am wondering if this is feasiable for React Native?

Thanks in advance.

My current code is similiar to what I've written above (cutting out the fat like handlers).
Attempting to wrap the `{props.children}` with a  element would stop the error, but would not render my nested child component.

I've tried searching for other similiar situations, but most of the examples do not work, or are in the ReactJS context.

Solutions Attempted:
[Creating Wrapper Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40111292/creating-wrapper-component)

Comment: You have `<Text>...</Test>` in your example. Typo?

Comment: Ah, apologies, yes, that's a typo, will edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved. It seems like there was a previous issue pertaining to how my interface type was being used.

```
interface IWrapperProps {
    children?: React.ReactNode | null;
    onPress?: () => void;
    testId?: string;
};
```

using this as my interface instead of using a hybrid type seemed to work for me.